# Feature is not added to site when I install an SPFx app with a list view command set a second time

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

I have an SPFx extension deployed to my tenant app catalog. The  app implements a list view command set and in package-solution I set `skipFeatureDeployment` to false so that site owners can add the app to their sites.

The package-solution file contains this one feature in the features section:

```
 { 
            "title": "HelloSign - this feature deploys a custom action to allow users to send documents to HelloSign for signature", 
            "description": "Deploys a custom action with ClientSideComponentId association", 
            "id": "40867f69-f2e4-454e-9c5f-9a511276ae75", 
            "version": "1.0.0.0", 
            "assets": { 
                "elementManifests": [ 
                    "elements.xml", 
                    "ClientSideInstance.xml" 
                ] 
            } 
}
```

When users first deploy the app, everything works fine. They see my custom action when they select a file in a document library. If they look at site features, they see the feature that was deployed via the app and it is Active. If they look at `{siteurl}/_api/Web/UserCustomActions` it shows the custom action itself.

If however, users remove the app from their site and then deploy it again, none of the above happens. They don’t see my custom action when they select a file in a document library. The feature that is deployed via the app does not show in site features. If they look at `{siteurl}/_api/Web/UserCustomActions` it is empty.

My `elements.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Title="HelloSign"
        RegistrationId="101"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar"
        ClientSideComponentId="6e6f9c79-b45f-4967-b6bd-f81169c8171e"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="....">
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

My `ClientSideInstance.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ClientSideComponentInstance
        Title="HelloSign"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar"
        ListTemplateId="101"
        Properties="..."
        ComponentId="6e6f9c79-b45f-4967-b6bd-f81169c8171e" />
</Elements>
```

Anyone have any idea why the feature would not be added back when a user deletes, and then re-adds the app?

Comment: Is there a reason they would be deleting it from the site and then re-adding it?

Comment: no reason, probably user error.

Comment: If the feature appears to have been re-installed and it doesn't load, then I would imagine it's a caching problem but if it the feature doesn't appear then it could be a bug with SharePoint.

Comment: yeah, the feature is not reinstalled. seems others must have hit this too. I just tested with a fresh commandset from yo@microsoft.sharepoint. Same exact thing.

Comment: cross posted to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/feature-is-not-added-to-site-when-i-install-an-spfx-app-with-a/m-p/3589060. See if anyone there has a clue.

Comment: Probably worth raising a Microsoft ticket, not being able to re-install from the user interface would suggest a SharePoint bug.

Comment: figured it out. deleting the app from recycle bin (level 1 and 2) then reinstalling works fine.

Comment: Great, you can post your own answer below if you wish!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. deleting the app from recycle bin (level 1 and 2) then reinstalling works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Always follow this process to completely remove SPFx app/extension from site:

1. Remove app/extension from site (site contents)
2. Delete the SPFx app from first-stage recycle bin
3. Delete the SPFx app from second-stage recycle bin (SCA recycle bin)

And then re-install the SPFx solution.